# Per group, find first N users with SUM(x) >= N

Tags: mysql, sql

Problem: Find the first 2 users who have at least 10 items in a category, per category.

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE items(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    datetime datetime,
    category INT,
    user INT,
    items_count INT
);
```

Sample data:

```
INSERT INTO items (datetime, category, user, items_count) VALUES
('2013-01-01 00:00:00', 1, 1, 10),
('2013-01-01 00:00:01', 1, 2, 1),
('2013-01-01 00:00:02', 1, 3, 10),
('2013-01-01 00:00:03', 1, 2, 9),

('2013-01-01 00:00:00', 2, 4, 10),
('2013-01-01 00:00:01', 2, 1, 10),
('2013-01-01 00:00:01', 2, 5, 10);
```

Desired result:

```
category    user
1           1
1           3
2           4
2           5
```

Note: As shown in the result, I need to be able to show preference towards a user when multiple users meet the requirements simultaneously.

SQL Fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58e60

This is what I have tried:

```
SELECT
  Derived.*,
  IF (@category != Derived.category, @rank := 1, @rank := @rank + 1) AS rank,
  @category := category


FROM(
  SELECT
    category,
    user,
    SUM(items_count) AS items_count,
    MAX(datetime) AS datetime


  FROM items


  GROUP BY
    category,
    user

  HAVING
    SUM(items_count) >= 10
) AS Derived


JOIN(SELECT @rank := 0, @category := 0) AS r


HAVING
  rank <= 2

ORDER BY
  Derived.category,
  Derived.datetime
```

But it is faulty. Not only does it not take user precedence into account, it would produce the wrong result with data such as this:

```
('2013-01-01 00:00:00', 1, 1, 10),
('2013-01-01 00:00:01', 1, 2, 1),
('2013-01-01 00:00:02', 1, 3, 10),
('2013-01-01 00:00:03', 1, 2, 9),
('2013-01-01 00:00:10', 1, 3, 1);
```

Additional information: I do not know if procedures could make a difference in this scenario, but unfortunately it is not an option either. The user running this query only has SELECT privilege.

Comment: the post's presentation just seemed to scream homework; and much like you used [tag:mysql], I was wondering if homework applied. That's all.

Comment: why is user_id 2 not visible, it seems to have 10 items in category 1

Comment: @BradChristie: [The homework tag is deprecated.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147100/161666)

Comment: @Akash Because I'm looking for the first two users per category that have reached 10 items, and user 3 met the requirements at `2013-01-01 00:00:02`, while user 2 met them at `2013-01-01 00:00:03`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried Gordon's query, but unfortunately it does not seem to work with large tables; after waiting 15 minutes for the result I decided to kill it.
However the following query worked very well for me, it chewed it's way through a table of ~6M rows in about 8 seconds.

```
    #Variable
SET @min_items      = 10,
    @max_users      = 2,
    @preferred_user = 5,

    #Static
    @category       = 0,
    @user           = 0,
    @items          = 0,
    @row_num        = 1;


--


SELECT
  category,
  user,
  datetime


FROM(
  SELECT
    category,
    user,
    datetime,
    IF (@category = category, @row_num := @row_num + 1, @row_num := 1) AS row_num,
    @category := category


  FROM(
    SELECT
      category,
      user,
      datetime,
      IF (@user != user, @items := 0, NULL),
      IF (@items < @min_items, @items := @items + items_count, NULL) AS items_cumulative,
      @user := user


    FROM items


    ORDER BY
      category,
      user,
      datetime
  ) AS Derived


  WHERE items_cumulative >= @min_items


  ORDER BY
    category,
    datetime,
    FIELD(user, @preferred_user, user)
) AS Derived


WHERE row_num <= @max_users;
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to find the users that meet your needs, you need the cumulative sum of the counts.  The following query finds the occasions when a user first reaches 10 units.  If the counts are never negative, then there is only one:

```
select i.*
from (select i.*,
             (select sum(items_count)
              from items i2
              where i2.user = i.user and
                    i2.category = i.category and
                    i2.datetime <= i.datetime
             ) as cumsum
      from items i
     ) i
where cumsum - items_count < 10 and cumsum >= 10
order by datetime;
```

To get the first two, you need to use MySQL tricks for counting within a group.  Here is an example that generally works:

```
select i.*
from (select i.*, if(@prevc = category, @rn := @rn + 1, @rn := 1) as rn, @prevc := category
      from (select i.*,
                   (select sum(items_count)
                    from items i2
                    where i2.user = i.user and
                          i2.category = i.category and
                          i2.datetime <= i.datetime
                   ) as cumsum
            from items i 
           ) i
           cross join
           (select @rn := 0) const
      where cumsum - items_count < 10 and cumsum >= 10
     ) i
where rn <= 2
order by category, datetime;
```

I have a problem with this approach, because nothing in MySQL says that the expression `@prevc := category` will actually be calculated *after* the calculation for `rn`.  However, it seems to be the case, and this seems to work in practice.